# IPP Printing from Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, printing, network-printer, cups

I have network IPP working on Ubuntu and Windows XP. On my Windows 7 instance, it refuses to acknowledge the remote server connection. Can anyone suggest how to configure this correctly?

My install steps are:

1. Add Printer
2. Add a Local Printer
3. Create a New Port and "Standard TCP/IP Port"
4. Enter hostname `http://host:631/printers/Printer_Name`

After that it says the printer is not detected, asks me to pick a driver, and finish up. Trying to use the device does not produce any output?

If anyone has got this work, I would really appreciate a fix.

Comment: Why are you telling it "Local Printer" when by definition, its a Networked Printer?

Comment: My understanding is that it is "local" in the sense that the port object is defined and allows Windows to ignore exactly where the end-point of the port is. I did try the "network" route, but it appeared to reach the same result (creating a new port reference), only with additional steps. I'll agree 100%, that who ever worked on this software did a bang-up job making it incomprehensible to a regular user.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, make sure IPP client is turned on:

Go into the **Control Panel** -> **Programs**, select "**Turn Windows features on or off**"

[image: Control Panel - Turn features on or off]

In the features dialog, scroll down to "**Print and Document Services**". Check "**Internet Printing Client**"

[image: Print Services - IPP Client]

Second, my original steps were not correct. Try the following:

1. In printer manager, click **Add a printer**, then **Add a network, wireless or Bluetooth printer**
2. Skip detection, go **Next**
3. The next dialog, "Type a printer hostname or IP address", in the middle box, where it says **Hostname or IP address**, use the following:

   ```
   http://HOST:631/printers/Printer_Name
   ```

   (If you didn't already know, you get this web address from the URL in your browser when using the CUPS webadmin)

   [image]
4. Click **Next**, if you get an error, something is wrong, use the  Back arrow (top-left) and change the URL, until Windows does not indicate it was not able to connect.
5. Continue with the remaining prompts, and it should all work.

Comment: That worked, but I had to restart after enabling the IPP client and/or use an account with admin privileges.

Answer (score 6):

I use IPP for printing from Win 7 to a linux print sever.  This is from the rollout sheet I use for new systems:

- Add a printer -> Network, Wireless, or Bluetooth
- Click STOP -> Printer I want isn't listed (mine is on a different subnet)
- Select Shared Printer by name -> http: //host:631/printers/PrinterName
- Wait for "Connecting to" to finish -> install driver when prompted

Answer (score 4):

The following steps worked for me:

1. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Settings`
2. Add a DWORD entry with name `PreferredConnection` and value of `0`
3. Add a new network printer as usual (New printer, network printer, printer isn't listed, etc.)
4. Enter `http://HOST:631/printers/PrinterName` in the location box and use the appropriate driver from the category.

Apparently Windows 7 and Server 2008 default to RPC IPP printing. The PreferredConnection setting reverts it to HTTP.

Comment: This also did the trick for me for Windows 8.1 64-bit dull edition with an ipp printer shared on my Mac

Answer (score 0):

Never use TCP/IP port as it is on 9100 or LPR. IPP use 631. So you have to add a network printer with a share name like [http://mybox:631]

Answer (score 0):

I just beat my head on this for a while. ..

My corp Pc had a proxy set by netsh winhttp

I'd removed the proxy setting in IE but still by attempts to connect to my home print server running Cups from windows 7 pro failed. Once I ran "netsh winhttp reset proxy" everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

An other thing to check on Windows is the `Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Printers\DisableHTTPPrinting` policy. When this key is set to true, even though windows will successfully install the CUPS printer, documents will not appear in the printer queue.