# CUPS network printer and Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, printer, cups, hp-laserjet

I have a HP LaserJet 2200d printer connected to my Ubuntu Server 12.04, and I can print files locally with `lpr` command. Here's the output of `lpstat`:

```
    cce@puntti:~$ lpstat -p -d
    printer HP_LaserJet_2200 is idle.  enabled since Thu 21 Mar 2013 01:23:31 AM EET
    no system default destination
```

I added and configured the printer through the CUPS web interface. The problem is, I can't set it up properly on my Windows 7 x64 client machine. When I try to connect to the shared printer from the Windows Network view, it yields "No driver found" message.

I can select a `HP LaserJet 2200 Series PCL 5` driver from the list manually, but printing with it doesn't seem to work, since the print job becomes instantly "complete" but the printer stays idle. No entries are added to the CUPS "completed jobs" log nor to `/var/log/cups/error_log`.

The official HP drivers for Windows 7 x64 are no use since they cannot detect a network printer properly.

On the server side the driver is `HP LaserJet 2200 hpijs pcl3, 3.12.2` from the `hplip` package.

Here's the CUPS configuration file:

```
    LogLevel warn
    MaxLogSize 0
    SystemGroup lpadmin
    # Allow remote access
    Port 631
    Listen /var/run/cups/cups.sock
    Browsing on
    BrowseOrder allow,deny
    BrowseAllow all
    BrowseLocalProtocols cups dnssd lpd smb
    BrowseAddress @LOCAL
    DefaultAuthType Basic
    WebInterface Yes
    <Location />
      # Allow remote access...
      Order allow,deny
      Allow all
    </Location>
    <Location /admin>
    </Location>
    <Location /admin/conf>
      AuthType Default
      Require user @SYSTEM
    </Location>
    <Policy default>
      JobPrivateAccess default
      JobPrivateValues default
      SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
      SubscriptionPrivateValues default
      <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
        Order deny,allow
      </Limit>
      <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
        Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
        Order deny,allow
      </Limit>
      <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default CUPS-Get-Devices>
        AuthType Default
        Require user @SYSTEM
        Order deny,allow
      </Limit>
      <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
        AuthType Default
        Require user @SYSTEM
        Order deny,allow
      </Limit>
      <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
        Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
        Order deny,allow
      </Limit>
      <Limit All>
        Order deny,allow
      </Limit>
    </Policy>
    <Policy authenticated>
      JobPrivateAccess default
      JobPrivateValues default
      SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
      SubscriptionPrivateValues default
      <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
        AuthType Default
        Order deny,allow
      </Limit>
      <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
        AuthType Default
        Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
        Order deny,allow
      </Limit>
      <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default>
        AuthType Default
        Require user @SYSTEM
        Order deny,allow
      </Limit>
      <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
        AuthType Default
        Require user @SYSTEM
        Order deny,allow
      </Limit>
      <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
        AuthType Default
        Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
        Order deny,allow
      </Limit>
      <Limit All>
        Order deny,allow
      </Limit>
    </Policy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I fiddled with the settings and it seems to work now. I chose `HP LaserJet 2200 Series PCL 5` as the Windows driver and `HP LaserJet 2200 Foomatic/Postscript` from the serverside. It seems to only achieve 600x600 dpi resolution though.

**Edit:** A new twist: only printing the test page (from Windows) works. So back to square one.

**Another edit:** Solved, I had to [add the printer as an IPP printer](https://superuser.com/a/301042/209178).