# Trouble printing over the internet through router to private network

Tags: router, printing, port

I am trying to send a print job from anywhere to a home network via its public IP address (I tried with and without a port number added ex. 40.230.2.2:9100), normal port number for RAW being 9100. I have a port forward setup on the router (which is a Verizon router/fiber modem) and still unable on my Windows 10 machine from outside the private network to "see" the printer for driver setup. I also created a port forward for SNMP to no success, yet when I forward port 80 to the printer I can pull its admin screen up from a browser. What am I missing to print from outside a private network? Also how might I setup printing through IPP, using the printer URI?
[image]

Comment: Have you considered the security implications of opening port 9100 to all and sundry? Maybe your provider is saving you from yourself? You should seriously look at setting up a vpn.

Comment: I really don't want to go VPN way, and I have read both prospects of not possible and done it without explaining how.

Comment: How do you plan for hackers not simply printing out screeds of garbage "for yhe lulz"?  If your provider allows traffic to port 9100 tcp, printing should just work - the protocol is even simpler then http. Maube your printer is detecting a request on a non rfc1918 ip that is not on a lan and refuding it. You would need tp break out a traffic analyzer to fond this. If that is whats hapenong you would need a very flexible router between the isp router and printer to readdress the source ip to appear on lan - making your security problrms even worse.

Comment: Hoe are you trying to see the printer from the internet? Becausr its not on the LAN you will need to hardcode its ip - it cant be autodiscovered.

Comment: The printer is connected directly to the router, and the router has a port forward set up to the printers IP address

Comment: Let me rephrade my last question - how have you configured your computer to see the printer when you are away from your lan?

Comment: On the windows 10 machine try searching for printer by IP

Comment: Thats could be your problem then.  Printing to port 9100 does not do any kind of printer negotiation, so it won't find the printer or know how to handle it.  You need to somehow (I've not done it on Windows 10) specify explicitly what printer you are printing to, including what print drivers to use.  In Windows 7 I vaguely recall going through a printer setup wizard, saying printer was not found, adding a local port (not a network port), then specifying an IP address and manually setting it up.

Comment: @davidgo as stated in question, and newly added screenshot, is where I put in IP address which fails, then tried IP:port which fails. Port name from what I have read really means nothing to actual connection and could be anything.

Comment: See the tick button that says query the printer? Im pretty sure that must NOT be ticked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48763/discussion-between-davidgo-and-user312083).

Comment: Ok thanks unchecking the query printer actually allowed me to get it to work , that and changing the autodetect to TCP/IP. Then of course choosing the proper printer driver (but I had done that previously).

Answer (score 0):

Windows cant see your printer in the internet, you must show it...

1. go to devices & printers on control panel
2. select any printer
3. select from window menu printer server properties
4. go to ports tab
5. add standard tcp port witch global IP (to router with port forwarding)
6. install manually printer or connect to net with printer and install it ( disconnect from net with printer)
7. go to printer properties
8. select tab ports
9. select added port, apply
10. go to general tab and try print test page

The printer must have configured correct gateway

to IPP printer forward 631 port

ports from article [How Network Printing Works](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783789(v=ws.10).aspx)  :

```
Service Name                             UDP                 TCP
Services for Macintosh (uses AppleTalk)  201, 202, 204, 206  201, 202, 204, 206
Internet Printing Protocol (uses HTTP)   80                  80
NWLink (uses IPX/SPX)                    213                 213
LPDSVC (accepts LPR)                     515                 515
LPR Port (sends LPR)                     721-731, >1023      721-731, >1023
Server (using SMB)                       137, 138            139
Server (using RPC)                       530                 530
Standard Port Monitor (using SNMP)       161, 162            161, 162
Standard Port Monitor (using LPR)        > 1023              > 1023
Standard Port Monitor (using RAW)        2000, 2501-2503,    2000, 2501, 2503, 
                                         3001, 6869, >=9100  3001, 6869, >=9100
```

Comment: I am assuming here that your #1-#3 is on my Windows 10 machine? In which case I have no printers installed and the ones that show are just the generic that "print" to file.
I believe I stated I already setup the router with port forwarding for RAW (9100) and SNMP.
The printer is connect to router directly, not another machine; so no sharing required. Not sure where on any machine besides router that you "select" port as mentioned in #4 and #8.

Comment: Probably you need only 9100. Any printer also generic print to file after select give you menu, but you can change direction, first install printer.... all points are to your windows machine...

Comment: ports descriptions is only to show show how many possible ways system can communicate with printer (using different protocols), but your printer must support protocol with you want to use. for example not all printers support ipp or SMB.

Comment: try install [ipp](http://superuser.com/questions/300986/ipp-printing-from-windows-7-ultimate)